# Eloquent group by product, ordering differently based on product

Tags: laravel-5, group-by, eloquent, sql-order-by

I currently have the following set up:

Category, SubCategory, Business, Enhancement & Product models.

- A `Category` has many `SubCategory`s
- A `SubCategory` has many `Business`s
- A `Business` may have one `Enhancement`
- A `Enhancement` must have one `Product`

A product could be an enhanced listing, a premium listing, or additional features.
If the business has brought either an enhanced or premium listing, it is recorded in the enhancement table.

So, product#1 = Premium Listing. Product#2 = Enhanced listing.

What I am wanting is to return all the businesses for a chosen SubCategory, grouping by the product that the enhancement is attached to. If the business has an enhancement, I'm wanting to randomise the order. If the business does not have a product, I'm wanting to order by name in ASC order.

So the result I'm expecting is to have a complete list of all businesses, with those with a Premium Listing, listed first in a random order. Then all businesses with an enhanced listing in a random order. Then all the other businesses that have no enhancement, in alphabetical order.

I currently have all the businesses listed in name order with the following code:

```php
SubCategory::where('slug', $subCategory)->where('category_id', $category->id)
    ->with(['businesses' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
}])->firstOrFail();
```

Category model:

```php
class Category extends Model
{   
    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\SubCategory');
    }
}
```

SubCategory model:

```php
class SubCategory extends Model
{

    public function businesses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Business');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Category');
    }
}
```

Business model:

```php
class Business extends Model
{

    public function subCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\SubCategory');
    }

    public function enhancements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Enhancement');
    }
}
```

Enhancement model:

```php
class Enhancement extends Model
{
    public function business()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Business');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Product');
    }
}
```

Product model:

```php
class Product extends Model { }
```

Migrations:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('featured_image');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->unsignedInteger('sort_order')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});


Schema::create('sub_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('featured_image');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedInteger('sort_order')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();

    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
});


Schema::create('businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('resort_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('sub_category_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('logo')->nullable();
    $table->text('description');
    $table->text('content')->nullable();
    $table->string('county')->nullable();
    $table->string('postcode')->nullable();

    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('resort_id')->references('id')->on('resorts');
    $table->foreign('sub_category_id')->references('id')->on('sub_categories');
});


Schema::create('enhancements', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('business_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
    $table->dateTime('from_date');
    $table->dateTime('to_date');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();

    $table->foreign('business_id')->references('id')->on('businesses');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
});


Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('image');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->float('yearly_price');
    $table->float('monthly_price');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Please post your migrations and relationships.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thanks, I have now added the additional information to my question

Comment: You wrote "grouping by the product ": You are referring to the ordering, right? You don't mean in the sense of `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I would like the businesses that have purchased the premium listing first in a random order. Then the businesses with an enhanced listing in a random order. then the rest of the businesses in alphabetical order.

Sorry if I'm mixing up words here.

Comment: How do you identify the premium listings? Is the product's name "Premium Listing"?

Comment: That's correct, but for ease, I'm using the slug which is premium-listing and enhanced-listing, which I access from the Business model, via the Enhancement Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```php
SubCategory::where('slug', $subCategory)
    ->where('category_id', $category->id)
    ->with(['businesses' => function($query) {
        $query->select('businesses.*')
            ->leftJoin('enhancements', function($join) {
                $join->on('enhancements.business_id', '=', 'businesses.id')
                    ->join('products', 'products.id', 'enhancements.product_id');
            })
            ->orderByRaw('FIELD(products.slug, ?, ?) DESC', ['enhanced-listing', 'premium-listing'])
            ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN products.slug IS NOT NULL THEN RAND() ELSE businesses.name END');
    }])->firstOrFail();
```